# Scaling orbit slider

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation, orbit

I'm working on a website that can be found there:
http://odesktestanswers2013.com/Metareviewer/

I'm working on a 1920px wide monitor and I noticed on my girlfriend laptop (a 14inch mac with Safari) that the slider displays two black strips above and below the slider.

My sliders' pictures are 1920px but I thought they would just scale (and that I obviously wouldn't have those black strips).

Anybody knows where that's coming from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the background-size values that you have defined. THey are using a % of the container. If you change your background-size to cover and your background-position to center center is will fix your problem

```
.main-wraper-present2 {
    background: url("../images/unes/une[2].jpg") no-repeat scroll center center #000000;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: You should really use one class to define the layout properties of all your slides. For example you could have all of your layout styles on .main-wraper-present then add slide number in your html after this selector

Comment: thank you!
That was not a permanent solution, I need to pass the image location into some PHP so that was going to change. but in the meantime I did that <div class="main-wraper-present slider-one/two">

Answer (score 0):

Try `background-size: cover;` on your `.main-wraper-present` and `.main-wraper-present2`.

EDIT:
Browser support for background-size has grown of late, with the current versions of most popular browsers now supporting the property, including Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Internet Explorer and Opera.